# Display error message if user entered less than minimum length

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display error message if user entered < the minimum length
here's my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<HTML>
<form name="form" action="action.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <span>Name</span><br>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" maxlength="20">
&nbsp;<label id="error"></label>&nbsp;<label id="errorAlpha">
  </label>&nbsp;<label id="errorMinOne"></label>
</HTML>

<javascript>
function validate()
{
  var valid = true;
  var alphabet =/^[a-zA-z ]+$/;

  if(firstName.value.match(alphabet) || firstName.value=="")
  {
    document.getElementById('errorAlpha').innerHTML=""; 
  }

  else
  {
    document.getElementById('errorAlpha').innerHTML="*Invalid Name";
    document.getElementById('errorMinOne').innerHTML="";
    valid=false;
  }

  if(firstName.value.length<2)
  {
    document.getElementById('errorMinOne').innerHTML="*Name is too short";
    valid =false;
  }

  else
  {
    document.getElementById('errorMinOne').innerHTML="";
  }
}

if(firstName.value=="" && lastName.value=="")
{
  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="*Field is empty";
  document.getElementById('errorTwo').innerHTML="*Field is empty";
  document.getElementById('errorMinOne').innerHTML="";
  valid = false;
}

if(firstName.value!="" && lastName.value=="")
{
  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById('errorTwo').innerHTML="*Field is empty";
  valid = false;
}

if(firstName.value=="" && lastName.value!="")
{
  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="*Field is empty";
  document.getElementById('errorTwo').innerHTML="";
  valid = false;
}

if(firstName.value!="" && lastName.value!="")
{
  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById('errorTwo').innerHTML="";
}
</javascript>
```

the error is when i type 1 it display both *Invalid name and *Name is too short, I want it to display only *Invalid name.. please help thanks

Comment: Return from the validate function when you display the first error message.

Comment: You also need to return `true` or `false` from the function, so that `return validate()` will pick up the correct value.

Comment: yes it does. i just add..else{document.getElementById('errorMinOne').innerHTML="";} and it works. thanks a lot. you really helped

Comment: Using element IDs as global variables is a bad idea. Acceptable alternatives are to access form controls as named properties of the form, use *getElementById* or *querySelector*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first three if else statements to this:

```
if(firstName.value.match(alphabet) || firstName.value=="")
{
     document.getElementById('errorAlpha').innerHTML="";    
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('errorAlpha').innerHTML="*Invalid Name";
    document.getElementById('errorMinOne').innerHTML="";
    valid=false;
}
if((firstName.value.match(alphabet) || firstName.value=="") && firstName.value.length<2)
{
    document.getElementById('errorMinOne').innerHTML="*Name is too short";
    valid = false;
}
```

Comment: I add: else {document.getElementById('errorMinOne').innerHTML="";} and it works. thanks mate xx

Answer (score 1):

In each of you `if` clauses return false at the end:

```
if((firstName.value.match(alphabet) || firstName.value=="") && firstName.value.length<2)
{
    document.getElementById('errorMinOne').innerHTML="*Name is too short";
    return false;
}
```